# The modal window closes when click on it

Tags: javascript, html, css

When clicking on the modal window (container-choose-number-phone-header) it closes, how to fix this problem? It is necessary that the modal window does not close when you click on it, but closes only when you click outside it.

Code:
HTML:

```
<!--     Modal window choose number phone      -->
<div class="background-header"></div>
<!--     Modal window choose number phone      -->
    <div class="container-menu-header-number-phone">
        <div class="svg-icon-header-phone">
            <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M0.750007 10.8488C-1.16228 7.01115 0.767201 2.77583 4.44387 0.569824C6.21403 -0.49226 8.50182 -0.0313341 9.72259 1.63336L12.431 5.32664C13.5838 6.89858 13.7604 8.98327 12.8887 10.7268L12.1785 12.1471C11.973 12.5582 11.9405 13.0338 12.1508 13.4427C12.5339 14.1872 13.3498 15.5071 14.9214 17.0786C16.4931 18.6502 17.8128 19.4662 18.5575 19.8492C18.9662 20.0595 19.4418 20.0271 19.8529 19.8215L21.2733 19.1112C23.0167 18.2396 25.1014 18.4162 26.6734 19.569L30.3667 22.2774C32.0314 23.4981 32.4922 25.7859 31.4301 27.5561C29.2241 31.2329 24.9889 33.1623 21.1512 31.25C17.9168 29.6383 13.7838 26.9709 9.40636 22.5936C5.02898 18.2162 2.36167 14.0832 0.750007 10.8488Z"
                      fill="black"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* MODAL WINDOW CHOOSE NUMBER PHONE */
.background-header {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.loaded-background-header {
    visibility: visible;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    opacity: 1;
}

.container-choose-number-phone-header {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 500px;
    height: 135px;
    background-color: #333333;
    border-radius: 10px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 350px;

    transform: translateY(-30%);
    transition: 300ms ease;
}

.show-modal-window-choose-number-phone {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition: 300ms ease;
    opacity: 1;
}

.choose-number-phone-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.number-phone-modal-window {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;

    cursor: pointer;
}
    /* CONTAINER PHONE ADAPTATION */
    .container-menu-header-number-phone {
        display: flex;
        width: 105px;
        background-color: #c8b197;
        height: 50px;

        border-left: 1px gray solid;
        border-top: 1px gray solid;
        border-bottom: 1px gray solid;

        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .svg-icon-header-phone {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

JS:
Actually here is the problematic code itself which for some reason does not work

```
const containerChooseNumberPhoneHeaderEl = document.querySelector('.container-choose-number-phone-header');

const backgroundHeaderEl = document.querySelector('.background-header');

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const popup = event.target.closest('.container-menu-header-number-phone');
    // console.log(popup)

    if (popup) {
        containerChooseNumberPhoneHeaderEl.classList.toggle('show-modal-window-choose-number-phone');
        backgroundHeaderEl.classList.add('loaded-background-header');

    } else if (!popup && containerChooseNumberPhoneHeaderEl.classList.contains('show-modal-window-choose-number-phone')) {
        containerChooseNumberPhoneHeaderEl.classList.remove('show-modal-window-choose-number-phone');
        backgroundHeaderEl.classList.remove('loaded-background-header');
    }

});
```

In fact, it seems to be written correctly, but it is not clear what the error is, why is it not working?
If you need additional code, I am ready to provide a link to the GitHub project

Comment: Please include enough code to reproduce the problem. At the moment `containerChooseNumberPhoneHeaderEl` is null because there is no element in HTML matching the  `.container-choose-number-phone-header` selector. May I also suggest considering if using really long identifiers makes the code easier to read - it didn't for me.

Comment: Hello, here are the sources: https://github.com/TopTTeDHbIu-DeJLbFuH4uk/Layout_LoftHouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const containerChooseNumberPhoneHeaderEl = document.querySelector('.container-choose-number-phone-header');
const backgroundHeaderEl = document.querySelector('.background-header');

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.closest(".container-choose-number-phone-header")) {
        return; // return when clicked on the popup area
    }

    const popup = event.target.closest('.container-menu-header-number-phone');
    console.log(popup)

    if (popup) {
        containerChooseNumberPhoneHeaderEl.classList.toggle('show-modal-window-choose-number-phone');
        backgroundHeaderEl.classList.add('loaded-background-header');

    } else if (containerChooseNumberPhoneHeaderEl.classList.contains('show-modal-window-choose-number-phone') && !popup) {
        containerChooseNumberPhoneHeaderEl.classList.remove('show-modal-window-choose-number-phone');
        backgroundHeaderEl.classList.remove('loaded-background-header');
    }
});
```

Something like this, you can adjust the behavior further as per you need and liking

Answer (score 0):

The popup closes when you click on the popup because in your javascript you are just checking click on the icon which triggers the popup so when clicked on the popup it goes in the else and hides the popup.

In the start of the listener check if the click is registered inside the popup container and if yes then return.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand what to do it) Could you write a code?)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).